# Python re.findall() Capitalized Words including Apostrophes

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm having trouble completing the a regex tutorial that went \w+ references words to this problem with "Find all capitalized words in my_string and print the result" where some of the words have apostrophes.

Original String:

```
In [1]: my_string
Out[1]: "Let's write RegEx!  Won't that be fun?  I sure think so.  Can you 
find 4 sentences?  Or perhaps, all 19 words?"
```

Current Attempt:

```
# Import the regex module
import re
# Find all capitalized words in my_string and print the result
capitalized_words = r"((?:[A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+)"
print(re.findall(capitalized_words, my_string))
```

Current Result:

```
['Let', 'RegEx', 'Won', 'Can ', 'Or ']
```

What **I think** the desired outcome is:

```
['Let's', 'RegEx', 'Won't', 'Can't', 'Or']
```

How do you go from r"((?:[A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+)" to also selecting the 's and 't at the end of Let's, Won't and Can't when not everything were trying to catch is expected to have an apostrophe?

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]+` means "all letters between A and Z and a and z." The range, as defined, does not include the apostrophes. Add them to the regular expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add an apostrophe to the second bracket group:

```
capitalized_words = r"((?:[A-Z][a-z']+)+)"
```

Comment: There is also no need for the space `" ?"`.

Comment: The tutorial went from [a-z] and \w+ does this to write a expression that does that with no explanation on how to combine the fundamentals so I found the one in my original post through searches. Unfortunately, what I thought the question wanted as output, which your answer accomplishes, isn't the desired outcome for the tutorial. I totally forgot about the sentence starting with I, I'll see if I can understand a way to capture it aslo.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can add a little apostrophe in the group `[a-z']`.
So it will be like `((?:[A-Z][a-z']+ ?)+)`

Hope that works

Answer (score 0):

While you do have your answer, I'd like to provide a more "real-world" solution using `nltk`:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, regexp_tokenize

my_string = """Let's write RegEx!  Won't that be fun?  I sure think so.  Can you 
find 4 sentences?  Or perhaps, all 19 words?"""

sent = sent_tokenize(my_string)
print(len(sent))
# 5

pattern = r"\b(?i)[a-z][\w']*"
print(len(regexp_tokenize(my_string, pattern)))
# 19
```

And imo, these are 5 sentences, not 4 unless there's some special requirement for a sentence in place.

Comment: Your going to have to complain with the person who wrote the tutorial to resolve that.